# Returning a 401 Unauthorized from WCF Web API in an MVC 3 App

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf-web-api, unauthorized

I'm using the WCF Web API (the latest version, which I think is 0.5, obtained from the VS2010 Ultimate integrated package dependency GUI).

I've got a simple API class exposed and in each method I'm making a call that performs authorization against the user. When the user is unauthorized, I throw an HttpResponseException with the 401/unauthorized code.

This works, and you can see that at some point in the Http Handler chain, the 401 was trapped. The problem is that the site in which the API resides contains ASP.NET Forms authentication... and so when *it* sees the 401, it tries to forward my client request to the logon page.

How do I disable this behavior for a particular sub-directory within my site? I've tried setting a location of "api" always allowing users... but I still throw a 401 which still causes ASP.NET to try and redirect me to the logon page.

I'm sure I'm just missing a simple configuration setting that tells forms auth to ignore requests for the /api/* directories, but I can't find any information on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have described the problem and it's solution here (with Preview4): [Basic Authentication with WCF Web API hosted in IIS / Getting a 404 - Disable Forms Authentication Redirection](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Basic-Authentication-with-WCF-Web-API-hosted-in-IIS--Getting-a-404---Disable-Forms-Authentication-Redirection/)

Comment: This is why link answers suck. The linked site/page is broken!